# What is this scenario?

Tags: lateral-thinking

It's wartime.

Fred and Gus are friends and soldiers.

When Gus decided to move far away from the cavalry, he saw an enemy coming toward his camp.

Fred also saw the enemy, and did his best to protect Gus, but because of his love for his friend, his country immediately lost the entire war.

*The entire battle is described above. No actions are taken prior to Gus's movement away from the cavalry.*

**What specific scenario is described above?**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think this is about

> [The Fool's mate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fool%27s_mate)

I also suppose that Fred and Gus are

> Two white pawns (the F Pawn is Fred and the G pawn is Gus)

Picture showing this:

> [image: Fool's mate]

Explanation:

> Invert the two moves of the white player showed in the gif. Gus goes away from the cavalry, Fred attempts to cover Gus, but they totally fail to protect their king! These are the moves, if you're interested: g4, e5, f3, Qh4

Comment: Good quick explanation and nice gif; and good that you mentioned that the white pawn moves in the gif are reversed.

Comment: You could make a note of the move notation - 1. g4 e5 2. f3 Qh5#.

Comment: White did not lose immediately upon the pawn moving forward, though. Black needed to make a move in order for white to lose.

Comment: @IanMacDonald But after that move white was pretty doomed to lose!

Comment: Not if black doesn't see the checkmate move...

Comment: Oh! I answered first and you still get all the up-votes, just because you found some gif on the net!

Comment: @ghosts_in_the_code, you didn't say the name of this scenario and said "this quite soon after the game beginning. Actually, these are the first moves!

Comment: In our chess group, we call this "idiot mate". ;-)

Answer (score 4):

It's

> A game of chess. The king is captured

when Fred goes to protect his friend.

Comment: on the right track. please expand.

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on @Ian 's answer...

This is quite soon after the beginning of the game. The white queen is out (not dead, I mean it is out of its position, free to move), so one white pawn is also out. Gus is the black pawn in front of the black knight, and Fred is the next pawn, which is in front of the black bishop. Both pawns are on the 'king-side' of the black army, and have not moved yet. Both sides may have made trivial moves to reach this setup.

> When Gus decided to move far away from the cavalry, he saw an enemy
>   coming toward his camp.

Gus moves 2 steps forward. White makes a move with the queen bringing it directly in front of Gus (no space).

> Fred also saw the enemy, and did his best to protect Gus, but because
>   of his love for his friend, his country immediately lost the entire
>   war.

As Gus is in danger of the queen, Fred moves 1 step forward to protect it. The queen moves to the edge of the board (adjacent to Gus), and gives a check along a diagonal line to the black king. This is also a checkmate.

Notes

- There should be other ways to answer this question, I've just given one of the simplest ones.
- Someone who has more time could please add an image to clarify the answer?

Comment: hint added in response to your answer